# Database lazy load using SwiftUI+Combine

Tags: swiftui, combine

I have a database. I want to display the content of the database.
The most obvious solution:

```
@State var items = Array(1...100)

List(items, id: \.self) {
     Text("Item \($0)")
 }
```

But what if I have tens/hundreds of thousands of records? What is the base approach for lazy loading?

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58122702/12299030?

Comment: There is a great read that is kinda related to this topic: https://www.vadimbulavin.com/infinite-list-scroll-swiftui-combine/

Comment: @Asperi in your case we should create a fake array which consumes a memory

Answer (score -1):

In SwiftUI 2.0 have **LazyVStack** and **LazyHStack** for your purpose, take a look https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/lazyhstack