# How can I create a LazyHStack that scrolls infinitely from the front?

Tags: swiftui

Variants of this question have been asked several times. The difference between my question and [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58103707/how-do-you-implement-list-paging-in-swiftui-or-infinite-list-view) is that I want infinite scrolling at the front (left) side of my `LazyHStack`.

My goal is to create a horizontally scrolling calendar where the rightmost date represents today, and the user can go back in time by scrolling to the left.

My strategy is to check every cell (as it appears) to see if it is close to the front of my stack view. If it's within a loading threshold, I then prepend more date cells. The problem is that any cell that is prepended will appear and trigger more cell loading, which causes an infinite loop.

Any suggestions?

Extra Credit: When the view appears, it should scroll to the current date (at the very end).

## Sample Code

The view showing the row of calendar cells.

```
struct CalendarView: View {
    
    @StateObject var vm = CalendarViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
            ScrollViewReader { proxy in
                LazyHStack {
                    ForEach(vm.array, id: \.self) { date in
                        CalendarCell(date: date).onAppear {
                            vm.loadMoreDatesIfNeeded(for: date)
                        }
                    }
                }.onAppear {
                    proxy.scrollTo(vm.array.last)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The view model responsible for loading new dates.

```
class CalendarViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published private(set) var array = [ Date() ]
    
    let batchSize: Int = 10
    
    func loadMoreDatesIfNeeded(for date: Date? = nil) {
        guard array.count > batchSize else {
            loadMoreDates()
            return
        }
        guard let date = date else {
            loadMoreDates()
            return
        }
        if array[batchSize-1] == date {
            loadMoreDates()
        }
    }
    
    private func loadMoreDates() {
        let startDate = array.first ?? Date()
        for i in 1...batchSize {
            let date = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -i, to: startDate)!
            array.insert(date, at: 0)
        }
    }
}
```

The calendar cell.

```
struct CalendarCell: View {
    
    var date: Date
    
    var title: String {
        let df = DateFormatter()
        df.dateFormat = "EEE"
        return df.string(from: date)
    }
    
    var subtitle: String {
        let df = DateFormatter()
        df.dateFormat = "d"
        return df.string(from: date)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .center) {
            Text(title)
            Text(subtitle)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things that can help here - `flipsForRightToLeftLayoutDirection` modifier and environment variable `layoutDirection`.

Try this:

```swift
var body: some View {
    ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
        LazyHStack {
            ForEach(vm.array, id: \.self) { date in
                CalendarCell(date: date)
                    .onAppear {
                        vm.loadMoreDates()
                    }
                    
            }
                .flipsForRightToLeftLayoutDirection(true)
                .environment(\.layoutDirection, .rightToLeft)
        }
    }
        .flipsForRightToLeftLayoutDirection(true)
        .environment(\.layoutDirection, .rightToLeft)
}
```

I actually have no idea why is it that way. It does not matter if you call the inner `flipsForRightToLeftLayoutDirection` with `true` or `false`. Also setting `layoutDirection` twice to the same value looks weird...  But it works ‍♂️